# Como voltar para dentro do while

Tags: python, while

Tenho um código de uma dungeon, em que o usuário pode escolher o caminho 1 ou o caminho 2, cada caminho leva a uma sala. Caso ele chegue a sala 8 preciso que um valor entre 1 a 5 seja sorteado e o faça voltar a sala respectiva a este valor. (Não posso usar mais de um if, elif ou else dentro do meu laço)

```
from random import randrange

import os

os.system('CLS')

tentativas = 1

sala = 1


while tentativas <= 7 and sala <= 7 and sala:

    print("Você está na sala: {}\nEscolha seu caminho".format(sala))

    print("[1] - Caminho Vermelho\n[2] - Caminho Preto")

    escolha = int(input())

    if escolha == 1:
        sala += 1
    elif escolha == 2:
        sala += 2
    else:
        ("Não existe esse caminho!")
    os.system('CLS')
    tentativas += 1


if tentativas >= 7:

    print("Você gastou todos seus recursos, não há mais saidas, você e seus companheiros morreram")

elif sala == 9:

    print("Você está na sala: {}\nVocê venceu!!".format(sala))

elif sala == 8:

    sala = input(randrange(1, 5))
```

gostaria de uma solução em que ao gerar o randrange meu código voltasse para dentro do loop.

Comment: você pode arrumar o codigo? você separou em varios blocos e tem identação faltando
```
coloque tudo assim
```

Comment: Poderia formatar o código para uma melhor exibição?

Comment: No seu primeiro while faltou informar a expressão pra variável sala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode transformar o while em uma função assim pode chamar ele quando quiser sem precisar ficar copiando e colando o mesmo código em diversos lugares, eu atualizei o seu código baseado no que eu entendi da sua questão, se não for exatamente o que você queria ou não entendeu algo do código é só falar que a gente da uma olhada.

```
from random import randrange

import os

def dungeon(tentativas, sala): # Esse código recebe como parametro a quantidade atual de tentativas e o numero da sala
    # Sempre que essa função for chamada ela realiza esse while
    while tentativas <= 7 and sala <= 7 and sala:

        print("Você está na sala: {}\nEscolha seu caminho".format(sala))

        print("[1] - Caminho Vermelho\n[2] - Caminho Preto")

        escolha = int(input())

        if escolha == 1:
            sala += 1
        elif escolha == 2:
            sala += 2
        else:
            ("Não existe esse caminho!")
        os.system('CLS')
        tentativas += 1
    
    # Após o while ser realizado ele retorna para os valores de tentativas e sala
    return tentativas, sala

os.system('CLS')

tentativas = 1
sala = 1

tentativas, sala = dungeon(tentativas, sala)

if tentativas >= 7:

    print("Você gastou todos seus recursos, não há mais saidas, você e seus companheiros morreram")

elif sala == 9:

    print("Você está na sala: {}\nVocê venceu!!".format(sala))

elif sala == 8:

    sala = randrange(1, 5)

    tentativas = 1
    tentativas, sala = dungeon(tentativas, sala)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, solucionou meu problema. Vou pesquisar mais sobre a função def para utilizar em códigos futuros, ficou realmente muito melhor.